# Showing that minimal polynomial of rank $r$ matrix has at most degree $r + 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, minimal-polynomials

**My attempt:**

Suppose the degree was $>r + 1$, i.e. $\mathbf{I}, \mathbf{A}, \ldots , 
\mathbf{A}^{r + 1}$ are linearly independent. This would mean
\begin{align*}
\forall \alpha _{0}, \ldots , \alpha _{r + 1}\colon 
\sum_{k = 0}^{r + 1} \alpha _{k}\mathbf{A}^{k} = \mathbf{B} \neq 0
.\end{align*}
Choose $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus \ker\!\left( \mathbf{B}\right)$
gives
\begin{align*}
\forall \alpha _{0}, \ldots , \alpha _{r + 1}\colon 
\sum_{k = 0}^{r + 1} \alpha _{k}\mathbf{A}^{k}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{B}\mathbf{v} \neq 0
.\end{align*}
In particular the vectors $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}, \ldots , \mathbf{A}
^{r+1}\mathbf{v}$ are linearly independent. However,
$\operatorname{im}\!\left( \mathbf{A}\right) = r$ and $
\operatorname{im}\!\left( \mathbf{A}^{k}\right)\subseteq \operatorname{im}\!\left( \mathbf{A}\right)$, yielding
a contradiction.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: I think I see what you are saying but you need to make sure to rule out the case $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\dots \alpha_{r+1} = 0.$ Besides, when you are obtaining contradiction by exhibiting a counterexample, you better explicitly describe that choice of example, rather than keep using $\forall$ quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't correct. That $\sum_i\alpha_iA_i\ne0$ for all $(\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{r+1})$ and $\sum_i\alpha_iA_iv\ne0$ doesn't make $v,Av,\ldots,A^{r+1}v$ linearly independent, because your choice of $v$ depends on the choices of the $\alpha_i$s.

E.g. let $A=\pmatrix{1\\ &2},\,v=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}$ and $B=I+A$. Then $I$ and $A$ are linearly independent and $Bv\ne0$, but $v$ and $Av$ are linearly dependent (because $Av=v$).